# Why won't my require() inside my img work correctly while using it with Bulma?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, bulma

I'm trying to dynamically display an image using `require()` in one of my `Bulma` components.  Also because I'm using webpack (I didn't use `create-react-app` to start my project), but for some reason, in the console, I get an error that says:

`ERROR in ./src/images/myImage.png 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.`

The file path in the error is incorrect, which's is weird to me.  Is it reading it differently than it's supposed to which's causing this error?

I've tried `<img src={myImage} alt="image"/>` (without `require()`) but it still doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

I've labeled it as `{/* Here's the problem */}` which points to which line's causing the error.

Here's my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import myImage from '../../images/myImage.png';

const Tiles = () => {
    return(
        <div className="tile">
            <div className="tile is-vertical is-8">
                <div className="tile">
                    <div className="tile is-parent is-vertical">
                        <article className="tile is-child notification">
                            <p className="title">Vertical...</p>
                            <p className="subtitle">Top tile</p>
                        </article>
                        <article className="tile is-child notification">
                            <p className="title">...tiles</p>
                            <p className="subtitle">Bottom tile</p>
                        </article>
                    </div>
                    <div className="tile is-parent">
                        <article className="tile is-child notification">
                            <p className="title">Middle tile</p>
                            <p className="subtitle">With an image</p>
                            <figure className="image is-4by3">
                                <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/640x480.png"/>
                            </figure>
                        </article>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="tile">
                    <article className="tile is-child notification">
                        <p className="title">Wide tile</p>
                        <p className="subtitle">Aligned with the right tile</p>
                        <div className="content">
                            {/* Here's the problem */}
                            <img src={require(myImage)} alt="image"/>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="tile is-parent">
                <article className="tile is-child notification">
                    <div className="content">
                        <p className="title">Tall tile</p>
                        <p className="subtitle">With even more content</p>
                        <div className="content">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Tiles;
```

Here's my webpack file:

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

const imageRule = {
    test: /\.(ico|gif|jpe?g|png)(\?.+)?$/i,
    use: [
        {
            loader: 'url-loader',  // defaults to file-loader (with options) when image size > options.limit
            options: {
                limit: 8192,
                name: 'assets/[sha512:hash].[ext]'
            }
        },
        'image-webpack-loader'
    ]
};


module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    mode: "development",
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                options: { presets: ["@babel/env"] }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
            },
            imageRule
        ]
    },
    resolve: { extensions: ["*", ".js", ".jsx"] },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist/"),
        publicPath: "/dist/",
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "public/"),
        port: 3000,
        publicPath: "http://localhost:3000/dist/",
        hotOnly: true
    },
    plugins: [new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()]
};
```

Comment: Pretty sure `require()` needs the string, not the thing you imported. So, use the actual image path in the `require()`.

Comment: @Colin I've tried that already, it doesn't work.  Hmm, I just noticed that upon hovering over `require()` I get something that says: `unresolved function or method`, but I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

You need a rule for images in your Webpack config. Here's the one I use:

```
const imageRule = {
  test: /\.(ico|gif|jpe?g|png)(\?.+)?$/i,
  use: [
    {
      loader: 'url-loader',  // defaults to file-loader (with options) when image size > options.limit
      options: {
        limit: 8192,
        name: 'assets/[sha512:hash].[ext]'
      }
    },
    'image-webpack-loader'
  ]
};
```

This rule will inline images less than 8KB. You need `image-webpack-loader` and `url-loader` in the `devDependencies` of your `package.json` and the rule goes in the `module.rules` sections of your Webpack config, i.e.

```
...
module: {
  rules: [ ..., imageRule, ... ]
},
...
```

For reference, here's the [full Webpack config](https://gitlab.com/gnaar/powder/blob/master/webpack.config.babel.js) which includes the snippet above.

Comment: ok, I tried that and looked at the docs but it still doesn't work.  I just posted my webpack file, may you please check it if you have a moment :)

Comment: yeah I do get the same error, I wrote it in my code correctly right?

Comment: Did you restart the app?

Comment: That's odd because the error message is definitely pointing to a loader issue and part of the problem was that you didn't have an image rule - did you install `image-webpack-loader` and `url-loader`, i.e. `npm i -D image-webpack-loader url-loader`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186276/discussion-between-greyskies-and-ic3b3rg).